# Are VIA x86 CPU's affected by Meltdown and Spectre?

Tags: cpu, x86, meltdown, spectre

Every article and website I've seen, including the official Meltdown research page only talk about Intel, AMD, ARM, and even a couple articles about PowerPC chips being affected by the Meltdown and Spectre exploits. But what about VIA x86 CPU's? I've never seen any article or official documentation talking VIA. I have a couple systems running on VIA CPU's (Nano L2007 and Eden x4) and want to make sure those systems aren't at risk since there doesn't seem to be any update or patch available for VIA systems nor mention or acknowledgement from anyone about Via x86 CPU's.

Comment: See this discussion: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/176782/are-via-cpus-vulnerable-to-spectre-meltdown-attacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per this discussion on the Security SE (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/176782/are-via-cpus-vulnerable-to-spectre-meltdown-attacks) the answer is "yes".

Because they are such a small niche of the market, little press has been devoted to them. Your best bet for accurate information would be to look for their own press releases and support documents on the subject.